# About the usage of the subscribeWith method with returning Subscriber

Tags: rx-java

I wonder why the `subscribeWith` method returns Subscriber but not strictly Disposable or maybe Subscription.

I think that the `subscribeWith` method were designed for the usage of RxJava 1.x's `subscribe` method which returns Subscription. Therefore, in 2.0, I think that the main usage of `subscribeWith` method would be the use with the Subscriber which implements Disposable.

Howerver, since the `subscribeWith` method can return a Subscriber, Subject-like usage (such as the below code) can be possible.

```
Subscriber<Long> subscriber = Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeWith(new Subscriber<Long>() {
      ...
    });

...

subscriber.onNext(999);

...
```

Is this OK or something that I should not do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subscriber in 2.x doesn't implement Disposable and would require wrapping/hijacking every Subscriber. You get back what you subscribed with and we have `ResourceSubscriber` and `DisposableSubscriber` that specifically implement `Disposable` in a correct way.

> Howerver, since the subscribeWith method can return a Subscriber, Subject-like usage (such as the below code) can be possible.

This is not recommended as you violate the protocol by possibly calling `onNext` concurrently. (This is not the result of `subscribeWith` because you could pre-create the `Subscriber`, call `subscribe()` and then call `onNext()` on the original `Subscriber` instance violating the protocol the same way.)

`subscribeWith` is indeed there to work with subscribers that support Disposable in a fluent manner and allow the following pattern:

```
CompositeDisposable cd = new CompositeDisposable();

cd.add(source.subscribeWith(new ResourceSubscriber<Integer>() { ... }));
```

[See](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber) our wiki for this and other 2.x details.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Bow, I'm sure about this.

Yes, I read Wiki and I thought `subscribeWith` would be for returning a Disposable. However, I checked the `subscribeWith` method, I found that it can return any Subscriber which must be the same as the parameter type. This made me wonder whether any other usages were concerned.

Also, it is true, my code does not matter with `subscribeWith`. I usually create a Subscriber instance in a `subscribe` method, so I did not come out that case. This is one thing that RxJava users should know what they should not do.

Comment: its working with observable, but flowable is throwing error !!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a same observer that you want to bind to different observable, use .subscribeWith ,so multiple Observables can use the same observer implementation.